# Excel VBA add border if active cell on certain row

Tags: excel, vba, border, cells

I am writing some VBA for a Gantt Chart spreadsheet.

I have 3 months worth of dates on row 5 and i can set the start date by entering a date in a cell which updates the whole sheet.

I have a range of cells for my chart L6:CZ42.  For this range, if the cell in row 5 is the 1st of the month, every cell in that column will have a grey dotted left border and nothing on the right.  This works how i want it to.

The problem is that it adds a grey border to the top and bottom of the cell which is OK for rows 7 to 41, but with row 6 i want a black top border and for row 42 I want a black bottom border.

I added this section of code trying to sort this problem but the syntax is wrong checking if it's on row 6

```
' If this is the first row (6) in the range then
' add a black continuous border to the top
If Cells(6, i) Then
    With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .ColorIndex = 1
        .Weight = xlThin
        .LineStyle = xlContinuos
    End With
End If
```

This is my whole code

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long
Dim CuDate As Date


For i = 12 To 104
CuDate = Cells(5, i).Value

' Are we on the 1st day of the month
If Day(CuDate) = 1 Then
    With Range(Cells(6, i), Cells(42, i))
        ' If this is the first row (6) in the range then
        ' add a black continuous border to the top
        If Cells(6, i) Then
            With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .ColorIndex = 1
                .Weight = xlThin
                .LineStyle = xlContinuos
            End With
        End If

        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .ColorIndex = 15
            .Weight = xlThin
            .LineStyle = xlDot
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        End With
    End With
Else
    With Range(Cells(6, i), Cells(42, i))
        ' If this is the last row (42) in the range then
        ' add a black continuous border to the bottom
        If Cells(42, i) Then
            With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .ColorIndex = 1
                .Weight = xlThin
                .LineStyle = xlContinuos
            End With
        End If

        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        End With
    End With
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line does not do what you think it does: `If Cells(6, i) Then`

It is equivalent to saying: `If Cells(6, i).Value = True Then`, i.e. "if the content of cell on row 6 and column `i` evaluates to `True` when implicitly coerced to a Boolean, then", which clearly is not what you want at all. Instead, try:

```
If ActiveCell.Row = 6 Then
```

The same reasoning goes for `If Cells(42, i) Then` further down in your code.

Comment: Many thanks.  That was what i was looking for.  I knew it was that line but didn't know the syntax

Answer (score 2):

[**Update:** Jean-François Corbett has corrected your code logic re: checking if the active cell is in row 6. But with the typo the code doesn't produce the top and bottom borders.]

Your code does not compile. Please consider using `Option Explicit` at the top of your code modules. The only way I could duplicate your issue was by removing `Option Explicit`. I set up the VBA Editor so it automatically places `Option Explicit` at the top of new modules.

The LineStyle Property must be one of the [XlLineStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241348%28v=office.12%29.aspx) constants:

- xlContinuous
- xlDash
- xlDashDot
- xlDashDotDot
- xlDot
- xlDouble
- xlSlantDashDot
- xlLineStyleNone

In your code, you wrote **xlContinuos** not **xlContinuous**. Once you make this correction the code should work.

Also, this is a minor point but technically the Worksheet_Change Event should be declared as follows:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

May I kindly suggest you take advantage of the built-in features of the VBA Editor as well as the help documentation?

Comment: Many thanks.  I didn't notice i had a speilling mistake in there until i ran it...the xLContinuous.  It's been a long time since i used VB so i do remember Option Explicit from many moons ago.  it all works now thatnks to both of you